# Dynamically change supervisor node to null

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I am pulling employee data from a SQL Server database to draw an org chart. My company has many departments (I think every company does). I only wanted to pull one specific department at a time.

On our database, every department head also reports to CEO or chair.. How can I change the `reportsToEmpId` column (at run time) for a department head to NULL? If the parent of the department head is not belong to this department.

Here is my reportsTo table structure:

```
empId, name, reportsToEmpId, deptId
100, John, 99, 1
101, Mary, 100, 1
102, Carol, 100, 1
99, Jim, null, 2
```

Since I only pull `deptId = 1`, and `Jim` is not `dept1`. Can I dynamically change `John`'s `reportsToEmpId` column to `NULL`?

```
select fields I need
from reportsTo r
join employee e on r.empId = e.empId
join groupHightlight h on ...
where deptId=1
```

I tried to use tmp table but it seems too cumbersome.

Original output:

```
empId, name, reportsToEmpId, deptId
    100, John, 99, 1
    101, Mary, 100, 1
    102, Carol, 100, 1
```

Here is my expected output: (However, I prefer not to make any change on the original table, since otherwise if I want to pull everyone who reports to CEO, then I lost the "connection" between departments).

```
empId, name, reportsToEmpId, deptId
    100, John, NULL, 1
    101, Mary, 100, 1
    102, Carol, 100, 1
```

Comment: So what are expecting as output here? And you only provided a vague bit of information for one of the three tables in your query.

Comment: Hi Sean, thank you.  I updated my question. (I added expected output to the bottom of my question :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can left join on both `empId` and `deptId`. If the employee being reported to doesn't have the same `deptId`, then `reportsToEmpId` will be `null`:

```
select r.empId, r.name, r2.empId reportsToEmpId, r.deptId
from reportsTo r
left join reportsTo r2
    on r2.empId = r.reportsToEmpId and r.deptId = r2.deptId
where r.deptId=1
```

Comment: I think this is the answer, since FuzzyTree's statement doesn't modify the original table. (which won't break down the relationship between departments).

Answer (score 1):

You have to use a `Self Inner Join` to achieve this

```
UPDATE T1
SET T1.reportsToEmpId = NULL
FROM reportsTo T1 INNER JOIN reportsTo  T2
     ON T1.reportsToEmpid = T2.empId
WHERE   T1.deptid <> T2.deptId AND T1.deptID = 1
```